# Hide All+Show Audio Actors Only - UDK

Tags: gameaudio, udk, implementation

I could start a blog on all these audio questions pertaining to UDK...

So I need to hide EVERYTHING other than the audio actors and emitters. Literally the only thing in the real time view should just be audio icons.

Anyone got any ideas? Chris? Hehe, I thought I would call ya out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this was a hard one to find.  Trying to show and hide exactly what you want can be a real pain.  There are two ways I have found:

1. Select the type of actor you want to view in the editor, then right-click and choose Visibility->Show Selected Only.  This will hide everything else but that particular type of actor, however it hides other types of audio actors along with it.
2. Use the Scene Manager (Browser Windows->Scene) as a list to select all audio actors on the map.  You can use the Auto-Focus checkbox to select/view the actors simultaneously.  Again, right-click on an actor and choose Visibility->Show Selected Only.  This give you an easily selectable list to use for show/hide.

Comment: Good call. :)  I wish there were an easier way to mass-select non-audio actors we happen to be using for audio.  I like working in a submap because I wind up using lots of (for example) generic points, etc. as static or mobile emitters, but there tend to be hundreds of those same actor types being used for non-audio things throughout the level.  Maybe a tagging option I'm not aware of...

Comment: Yeah, we are using streaming levels in our map to help separate audio actors from the rest.  It also allows us access to everything without messing with any of the mappers work.
As for selecting, I think you and I are looking for the same thing. I want something like selection groups, where once I have a bunch of actors selected I could save and recall that selection again easily.  I guess I am just so used to show/hide groups in Pro Tools. 

Comment: @ChrisEngineAudio Yep, my requirement is a bit of the same. This helps when working remotely with a developer by a million. Thanks again you all!

Comment: @ChrisEngineAudio @C3Sound Hey, found it.  Actors have a "Group" property under the "Object" tab in their Properties.  Populating this field creates groups which are accessible via the Group Browser (to the right of the "Actor Classes" tab in the Browser Window).  You can check or uncheck group names in this list to show/hide the actors you've grouped.  Note to self: actually have UE3 up for reference the next time I comment here. :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to simplify this is to create an audio-specific submap (if you haven't already) and move (or place upon creation) all of your audio actors there.  You can then show/hide the audio submap via the usual checkboxes in the Generic browser's level list.  This won't help for audio objects you've attached directly to actors that reside in other submaps or the main map, as UE3 won't let you create cross-level references.  It should help you to isolate a good deal of your audio actors -- possibly the majority, depending upon how you've implemented so far.  If they're already distributed throughout a map with lots of non-audio actors in it, you may have to "manually" select them and move them to the audio submap.

Good luck!